# Move text and images on press and hold windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, tapandhold

My windows phone 8 application requires to move an image and/or text to desired positions if needed by user by pressing and holding tht text or image.
The text and image will be prepopulated to their fixed positions. Now if user wants to rearrange their positions they can do so by hold gesture on the required text or image.
Is this possible?. And if yes any code snippets or links available on the same?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! It is possible.

See the Drag and Drop in Windows Phone [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/07/10/drag-amp-drop-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone.aspx)

You need to integrate with the gesture hold event.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for sharing the link. Have not tried it yet, but looks good. But here if the image moves back to original position if uncollided with other image. Have to make some yweaks but for good for starters.